# Destructuring object assignment to existing variable

Tags: javascript, object, ecmascript-6, variable-assignment

I have two variables:

```
let a, b;
```

No I'd like to do a destructuring object assignment with these existing variables. When creating new variables isn't a problem, you might go ahead with:

```
let {x, y} = myFunc();
```

However, as I want to overwrite the existing variable, I'm asking myself about the preferred way. Using

```
{a, b} = myFunc();
```

will cause:

> expected expression, got '='

Of course I could do:

```
let ret = myFunc();
a = ret.a;
b = ret.b;
```

But this seems to be an overhead.

How to do a destructuring object assignment to existing variables?

Comment: Put the expression in parentheses `({a, b} = myFunc())`, otherwise `{}` is interpreted as a block.

Comment: @LUH3417 Works! Would you please be so kind and post this as an answer with background information about `()`? If so, I'll accept it.

Comment: Sorry, it's a dupe, search similar questions on SO.

Comment: @LUH3417 Would you please be so kind and post the links where you think it is a duplicate of?

Comment: Didn't find this one.

Comment: @dude Easy, [first result](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=object+destructuring) ;)

Comment: @str sometimes you're not able to see the wood for trees, or just using the wrong keywords.

Comment: @dude Sorry, I was AFK, but str already helped out.